# How to generate MapKey for API 2.1

Tags: java, android, google-maps, annotations

I've done practices on Map View so many times already. But i've hard time trying to generate map key this time.

I dont get the Singup page for generating map APi key after once i got the MD5 code for application & keystore.

Can anybody tell me the procedure how can i generate map key now.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use keytool plugin which is can be embedded in eclipse
[Keytool website](http://keytool.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Reviewers: this is *not* a link-only answer. It could do with more explanation, but it is an answer, even without the link.

Answer (score -1):

You problem is that your are trying to get the key using the MD5 fingerprint when you should use the SHA1 fingerprint. In [my guide to getting the Google Maps API V2 Key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403), I suggest the following steps:

1. Navigate to `c:\program files\java\<your jdk or jre instllation>\bin>`
2. Find your SHA1 key using the command `keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\<your user name>\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android`
3. Head to the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and create a new project
4. Head to the **Services** section and turn on the **Google Map Android API V2**
5. Open the **API Access** section and press the **Create new Android key…** button. In the window that opens you will have to enter you SHA1 key from step 2, adding a semicolon and your application package name after a semicolon as in this example:

```
45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example.your_project_name
```

After pressing the **Create** button you will recieve you own Google Maps API V2 key for Android.